# Symfony 2.3 different locales on different paths

Tags: php, symfony, routes, locale, multilingual

I need to achieve different locales on different paths.
Now exists **web page** under path `/` and **admin** page under path `/admin`.

**Admin user** to have EN or FR locale (depends on what he chosen) on **web page** and only EN in **admin page**. Locale cannot be contained in a URL path.

The issue is that when logged admin checks **web page** with FR and goes on **admin page** which is on EN, the **web page** has to be on FR when the admin comes back.

I am thinking about storing separate locales for **web** and **admin** pages in session and read them depending on *path*.

Any suggestions without hardcoding or a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add requirements for the route to define list of possible locales.

See [Adding Requirements section for Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements)

> ```
> # app/config/routing.yml
> homepage:
>     path:      /{_locale}
>     defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Main:homepage, _locale: en }
>     requirements:
>         _locale:  en|fr
> ```

Comment: There is a requirement that `locale` cannot be in the URL.

Comment: sorry, missed this. if you are using manual locale selection (and not autodetection or something like) this is not matter of path at all - really just store locale in the session. Also you can create a onRequest event listener that set up proper locale for user according to the uri and his preferences.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was creating an event listener which forces a desired locale depending on accessed path. The path is parsed simply with regexp.